# Displaying multiple rows in one

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'd like to display multiple rows in one. I have this as output:

```
name | value
------------
A    |     1
A    |     2
A    |     3
B    |     2
B    |     4
C    |     6
```

And I'd like to have:

```
name | value
------------
A    | 1,2,3
B    |   2,4
C    |     6
```

My current query is something like this:

```
SELECT name, value 
FROM table 
ORDER BY name
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
create table tab(name varchar(50), val int);

insert into tab values ('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('A', 3), ('B', 2), ('B', 4), ('C', 6);

.mode column
.headers on

select name, group_concat(val, ',') as list from tab group by name order by name;
```

Output:

```
sqlite> select name, group_concat(val, ',') as list from tab group by name order by name;
name        list
----------  ----------
A           1,2,3
B           2,4
C           6
```

Comment: My current query is something like this: SELECT name, value FROM table ORDER BY name. How would I implement your solution?

Comment: I only get one row as output.